# Having issue loading image dynamically when url link is from object and not string

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically ive been stuck on this issue for a while where i created a show image function. It works well only when i add a url string and not my url i assigned to a forEach loop. Below will give you a complete understanding:

```
function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt;

    // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
    document.getElementById("inner-screen").appendChild(img)
}

var inputval = this.state.value.toLowerCase();
var data_map = Data.forEach(function(i){
  if(inputval === i.name){
    // not returning image
    foo.innerHTML = i.element_type + "<br>" + show_image(i.imgUrl, 100, 100);
 // returning image
        foo.innerHTML = i.element_type + "<br>" + show_image("www.example.com/img", 100, 100);
  }
```

as you can see everything is pretty straight forward. all info from "database" and i use that term loosely since the database is an array of objects in another js file.

Comment: It would help if you showed an example of the data. Also you are using `Data` to iterate, not sure where that is coming from.

Comment: @FutoRicky its in another js file in the same directory. if you dont mind you can check my repo.https://github.com/Nicholas-Rotondo/pokdex

Comment: @FutoRicky basically its a pseudo-json file, since im too lazy to create any real databases atm. im iterating over Data which is an array that holds multiple pokemon object and over each iteration my inputval variable matches the name of any of the objects, if they match it returns the data i specify in this callback function within the foreach

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: You should include *all relevant* information directly in your question, you shouldn't expect us to search through all of your code in order to help you - you need to help us to help you. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and [How to make a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: FluffyKitten this is about as relevant as it gets. the problem derives specifically from this code snippet and no where else in my project, i just offer repo link to give people a little extra detail. as to @FutoRicky no but im going to keep working on the issue through the night and see if i can rig something, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

These are based on the information provided and the link to the repo which I only glazed at.

- The `Data` constant should be lowercased as in javascript coding conventions.
- Only the first object in the array contains the `imgUrl`
- Try getting the data using `i["imgUrl"]` instead of `i.imgUrl`

If none of these work, you should provide more info to make clearer what exactly is causing the issue.

Comment: Please see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "***Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem***". Its not possible to give good, complete answers to questions that don't contain enough information. Save your well-intentioned efforts for people who have put the effort into their question so that it contains the information we need to help them - they have to help us to help them!